# Signal extraction from Float Switch without disturbing existing circuit

Tags: sensor

I have a small coffe vending machine,and it has a floating sensor to signal when I run out of water.

I need to extract that information without affecting the existing circuit.

So, the sensor works as a switch, meaning it is closed or open.

My idea to extract the information in a circuit as follows,

[image]

Adding a small resistance in series in order to not affect the unknown circuit, that way a current in the resistant would produce a voltage that I can amplify and use to control a pump.

The problem I have is that I cannot measure any voltage drop across the resistance, and I'm reluctant to use a higher resistance because I could negatively affect the unknown circuit.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you start by measuring the voltage across the switch when it is open? Is it AC or DC? Next, try putting a variable resistance across the open switch (continuing to monitor the voltage) in order to determine how much current is flowing and what the "unknown circuit" considers the switching threshold to be. Only then can you proceed with the design of an interface.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is an AC system, running at mains voltage; kitchen appliances tend to be simple. However, it may be a modern design with a processor and display.

If it is a DC circuit, use an opto-coupler; find the polarity and connect accordingly. If it is AC, reverse connect a diode across the opto input. You may need to buffer the output in order to drive a relay. If the unknown circuit is a high impedance input then this won't work, but you could try sensing a change of voltage across the sensor. Either way you need an auxiliary power supply, or a detailed schematic to use the processor supply if it exists.

Comment: Thanks, it was in fact an AC system, and it's running 20 uA so I'm gonna proceed with the opto-coupler.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just measure the voltage across the two terminals of the switch?  If it's (near enough) zero, the switch must be closed.  If it's non-zero, the switch must be open.

What that non-zero voltage is depends on what circuit is currently using the switch, but should be easy enough to measure.